# Корректна ли конструкция: "задача — чтобы..."?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> Задача СМИ — чтобы единственным интересом человека было потребление в той или иной форме.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ: такая конструкция корректна.

Полное предложение выглядело бы так: "Задача СМИ состоит в том, чтобы единственным интересом человека было потребление в той или иной форме".

Тире стоит на месте отсутствующих членов предложения.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> Порошенко не хочет, чтобы Яценюк, готовясь к следующим выборам, ушел из правительства и занял удобную политическую позицию критика власти, задача ― чтобы он все-таки взял на себя политическую ответственность за экономические реформы. [Павел Шеремет. Дожить до транша // «Огонек», 2015]
>
> ― Что касается центров кинезитерапии, то моя задача ― чтобы они появились в каждой больнице, в хорошей городской больнице. [Вера Краснова. Двигайся или заболеешь // «Эксперт», 2014]
>
> Работаем над своим сайтом; наша задача ― чтобы человек, совершая покупку, как можно больше операций делал на сайте, самостоятельно. [Елена Николаева. Конвейер на диване // «Эксперт», 2014]
>
> Твоя задача ― чтобы Дашкевич открыл дверь.[Александр Терехов. Каменный мост (1997-2008)]
>
> Поэтому когда мы говорим о духовном образовании в современном российском обществе, то мне кажется, наша задача ― чтобы мы стали примером, в своем образовании показали пример...[А. И. Осипов. Духовное образование и современное российское общество (2006) // , ]
>
> ― Передо мной стояла задача, ― вспоминает он, ― чтобы коммерческие структуры получали квалифицированных специалистов, которые создавали бы программные продукты с соответствующим экономическим эффектом, получали доход. [Галина Мялковская. Алгоритм Бухбергера, или Метод раскручивающейся спирали // «Знание - сила», 2005]
>
> Задача ― чтобы пороховой заряд полностью сгорел, когда пуля пройдет 2/3 длины канала короткого пистолетного ствола. [Глушитель Стечкина (2004) // «Боевое искусство планеты», 2004.12.09]
>
> Они же сами утверждают, что когда в прессе публикуется информационное сообщение о выборах, оно всегда сопровождается комментарием, а задача политтехнологов ― чтобы этот комментарий был выгоден их клиентам. [Константин Катанян. Оборотни, упыри и вурдалаки // «Время МН», 2003]
>
> По словам Зюганова, сейчас компартию поддерживает 30 млн избирателей, а задача партии ― чтобы «каждый привел на выборы хотя бы еще одного сторонника КПРФ». [Александр Садчиков. Левые и богатые (2003) // «Известия», 2003.07.24]